# Command garbled - solaris sed doesn't like my regex

Tags: bash, unix, sed, solaris

I struggle with regex's at the best of times but having honed this one on a regex test site I can see it should work. However when I put it into sed on Solaris it gives me a garbled command error:

```
cat p.csv | sed -e 's/(([^,]+,){8})([^,]+)(,.*$)/\3/g'
```

I can't understand what is wrong with this. If I use xxx instead of the capture group I just get the full input, which makes even less sense to me!

My regex is supposed to allow me to extract a column of a csv file - I have reasons for wanting to use sed and regex.

Comment: BRE capture groups have to be escaped: `\( \)`, BRE has no `+`, and only some seds support it in BRE as an extension, but is has to be escaped, `\+`, quantifiers have to be escaped `\{ \}`.

Comment: I don't know if solaris sed supports extended regular expressions, but if it does, your command should work. `sed -E` is commonly used for ERE.

Comment: If you can't have ERE and `\+` is not supported, you have to use `[^,][^,]*` instead of `[^,]+`. Also, the second capture group doesn't seem to be necessary in any case. And the fourth one.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks for this - I didn't realise that the version of sed I was using was so limited. I found a gnu sed was also available on the same machine and everything worked fine after that.